# How do I ignore the citations in a "list of figures" section when sorting by ascending order?

Tags: bibtex, captions, citing

I'm currently ordering by bibliography by ascending order based on the first occurrence. However, some of my figures have captions with citations in them, and so the "list of figures" section at the start of the document has the first occurrences of those citations. This causes citations that happen way down in the document to get assigned `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` and so on.

How can I ignore those and make sure they get assigned the right number?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Surely you don't need the citation call-outs to show up in the List of Figures. Hence, use the optional argument of `\caption` to state the caption text as it should show up in the LIst of Figures. E.g., `\caption[Text without \cite command]{Text with \cite command}`. (In your document, the numbers assigned to the citation call-outs depend on the first occurrence of the `\cite` commands. Since the LoF occurs early on, the \cite commands in the LoF matter.) After changing the caption directives, be sure to recompile the document twice to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: Typically one uses a separate "short caption" without citations: e.g. `\caption[short caption]{long caption}`